# Obtener indice de elemento seleccionado en un JTree (Java swing)

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo una ventana con un componente JTree. Los datos que se muestran en el los extraigo de un array (el cual esta ordenado como se debe mostrar en el arbol e indica que nodo es hijo de quien).
Lo que quiero es que al seleccionar un elemento en el JTree, saber cual es el objeto original en el array, es decir, su indice (por eso aclaro que el orden de los elementos en el JTree y en el Array es el mismo).
¿Como puedo calcular/obtener ese indice?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el  [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas 
 [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y 
 [ejemplo minimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden.Sería buena idea que empezaras a hacerla y preguntaras por dudas específicas.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre una manera, lo comparto por si alguien mas lo necesita...

```
private int obtenerIndiceSeleccionadoEnJTree(javax.swing.JTree arbol){
    // JTree auxiliar
    javax.swing.JTree aux = new javax.swing.JTree(arbol.getModel());
    // expande los nodos del JTree auxiliar para luego obtener el numero de fila correctamente
    for (int i = 0; i < aux.getRowCount(); i++) {
        aux.expandRow(i);
    }
    // Obtiene el numero de fila del elemento seleccionado basandose en la ruta hasta el elemento
    return aux.getRowForPath(arbol.getSelectionPath())-1;
}
```

Dependiendo de lo que necesiten puede ser que deban borrar el -1 en el return.